# How can I center a tooltip above my control in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, tooltip

I want to be able to display a tooltip **centered** above my control.

I know how to customize the XAML used to display the tooltip using the TooltipService, however, the placement options the TooltipService makes available only allow you to specify top, bottom, left, right, etc. They don't let you specify an alignment once on the given side.

By simply using the TooltipService, selecting a placement of "Top" puts the tooltip above the control and has it aligned to the left side of the control. If there is not enough room for it to be aligned left, it moves it to be aligned on the right side of the control.

I want the tooltip to be centered on the top of the control. I don't want it to anchor to either the left or the right while on top.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

you should check out the TooltipService. MSDN documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752368%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36930/Tooltip-service-and-tooltip-facility-of-WPF.aspx) is a (WPF) sample from CodeProject.

Comment: I know about the TooltipService. I mention that in my post. I am trying to center the tooltip not just display one.

Comment: TooltipService allows you to position the tooltip if you manipulate it's properties.  It might not work, its just a possible starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

A quick shot: you could create your own TooltipService class to extend the possibilities of the existing one to manipulate a Tooltip instance.

[Here](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2010/07/silverlight-popup-with-target-placement.html) you can find a nice class to help position a popup by specifying a list of preferred positions, like the TooltipService does for tooltip. You can specify a Top placement with Center HorizontalAlignment. I know this isn't a tooltip but I thought you could check it out and use it to create a BetterTooltipService.